# Fast FullText search for one occurrence of exact phrase in MySQL sorted by id

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization, exact-match

I'm using MySQL/InnoDb. I have this table `News` which has about 3,000,000 records and I hope it gets 7,000,000 more. Currently I use the following query to fetch records from `News` table with exact phrase inside their `title` or `content`:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ('"My Phrase"' in Boolean Mode)
```

But the results aren't satisfying. For me, when searching for an exact phrase, it's logical to see the latest news with that phrase first. I don't need the results to be sorted by relevance. I don't mind if the first record found has 1 occurrence of my phrase and the second one has 10. All I care is `ORDER BY time_added` or `ORDER BY id`. So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ('"My Phrase"' in Boolean Mode) ORDER BY id DESC limit 40
```

But when I try to `EXPLAIN` this query, I see that it is `Using filesort` as I excpected.

Is it the only way MySQL works? Can I get the results sorted by time in an optimal way?

**Edit:**

MySQL version: 5.6.34

`News` table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `News` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(400) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `url_title` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `link` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `link_unique_index` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `source` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT,
 `category` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `description` varchar(600) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `has_content` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `content` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `has_image` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `image_orientation` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `original_image` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `keywords` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `year_added` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
 `date_added` date NOT NULL,
 `time_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `time_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `number_of_views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_view_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `number_of_positives` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `number_of_negatives` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `number_of_votes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `number_of_suggestions` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_suggestion_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `lui` (`link_unique_index`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `st` (`source`,`time_added`),
 KEY `snv` (`source`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `snvo` (`source`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `sct` (`source`,`category`,`time_added`),
 KEY `scnv` (`source`,`category`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `scnvo` (`source`,`category`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `ct` (`category`,`time_added`),
 KEY `cnv` (`category`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `cnvo` (`category`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `hicdnv` (`has_image`,`category`,`date_added`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `sdnv` (`source`,`date_added`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `sdnvo` (`source`,`date_added`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `scdnv` (`source`,`category`,`date_added`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `scdnvo` (`source`,`category`,`date_added`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `cdnv` (`category`,`date_added`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `cdnvo` (`category`,`date_added`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `dnv` (`date_added`,`number_of_views`),
 KEY `dnvo` (`date_added`,`number_of_votes`),
 KEY `clst` (`category`,`last_suggestion_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `slst` (`source`,`last_suggestion_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `nv` (`number_of_views`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `nvo` (`number_of_votes`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `t` (`time_added`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `lvt` (`last_view_time`) USING BTREE,
 FULLTEXT KEY `title_content` (`title`,`content`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Comment: Add output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE News` and which version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using a tip I found from [Rolando on DBA.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/145558/24505):

```
SELECT News.* FROM (
SELECT id FROM News
WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ('"My Phrase"' in Boolean Mode) 
) matches
INNER JOIN News
ON News.id = matches.id
ORDER BY News.id DESC
limit 40
```

Comment: If the goal was to avoid "filesort", I suspect this fails.  It probably also says "using temporary".  Let's see both `EXPLAINs`.  OTOH, what this query provides is looking at the `*` only 40 times, not "as many as needed by the `MATCH`.  So it is likely to be faster.

Comment: As @RickJames said, it's `Using temporary; Using filesort`. I don't know if it's as fast as I can get. It's a great method for small tables, but I don't recommend it for large tables. It's obvious that for most frequent used phrases, it gets slower. One of my test cases with such phrase took 300 seconds before I killed the process. I would vote up your answer but I can't because of my reputation.

Comment: @Mowji There are a few other tips linked from that post on dba.stackexchange.com that I linked. I suggest going through them and giving them a shot. In particular, see if switching to just using normal indexes and LIKE improve performance. At the end of the Using temporary; Using filesort doesn't necessarily mean the query is going to perform slowly, so focus more on actual performance than simply getting rid of that from the explain plan.

Comment: @Mowji - 300 seconds -- was that with under 40 rows matching?  Or over?

Comment: @WillemRenzema I will test other methods and I will let you know.

Comment: @RickJames I limited the query for 40 rows and I got 300 seconds (at least).

Comment: @Mowji - I am not referring to `LIMIT 40`, but rather how many rows actually match.  `LIMIT` may _or may not_ be optimized such that it looks only at 40 rows.  Continued...

Comment: Since there are more than 40, Willem's solution brings efficiency to the table.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, I misunderstood you before. I didn't get the results but I expected to have about 1 million records with that match at least.

Comment: A million records:  I _think_ it must fetch the million _full_ (`*`) records, sort them, then deliver 40.  With Willem's answer, it fetches a million `ids` (much less bulky), sort them, pick 40, then get _only_ 40 full records.  More steps, but less stuff to shovel around.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, Willem's answer works with minimum requirements but still suffers from those MORE STEPS ('Using temporary and filesort').